# Liff.getProfile() is returning an undefined object

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm a starter in developing Liff app and this is what I encountered: when I execute liff.getProfile(), it returns undefined, meaning that I can't get any of the user's infromation.
What have I done wrong or haven't done?

I've searched online but it seems that few people use React to develop a Liff app.

Below is my App.js

```
// import liff from '@line/liff';
// import init from '@line/liff/dist/lib/init';
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './App.css';

const liff = window.liff
const myliffId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    console.log(5)
    this.state= {
      text : '0'
    }
  }
  // https://f4c2d15b579f.ngrok.io

    // start = async () => {
    //   liff.ready.then(()=>{
    //     console.log(liff.getOS())
    //     return <div>hello</div>
    //   })
    //   await liff.init({liffId: myliffId})
    // }
  
  componentWillMount = () => {
    liff
      .init({
        liffId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", // Use own liffId
      })
      .then(() => {
        if (!liff.isLoggedIn()) liff.login({ redirectUri: 'https://11d493b7e4c8.ngrok.io' });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.code, err.message);
      }).then(()=>{
        liff.getProfile()
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('wrong connection')
      })
      .then((profile)=>{
        console.log(profile)
        this.setState({
          text: profile.userId,
        })
      })
  };

  print = () => {
    console.log(55555)
  }
  // componentDidMount = () => {
  //   return <div>hllllll</div>
  // }
render(){
  console.log(liff.getLanguage())

    return (
      
      <div >
        hi
        <button>ho</button>
        <div class="buttonGroup">
              <div class="buttonRow">
                  <button id="openWindowButton" onClick={this.print}>{this.state.text}</button>
                  <button id="closeWindowButton" onClick={this.print}>Close LIFF App</button>
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  }
export default App;
```

I really need some help in this, everyone seems to develop LIff in angular. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
liff.init({ liffId: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx' })
  .then(async () => {
    if (liff.isLoggedIn()) {
      console.log(liff.getProfile());
    } else {
      liff.login();
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
```